# Dropdown list box goes as wide as needed even with width set

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a dropdown list box that displays data from my database. Problem is that some records are quite long so the width of the dropdown box extends past the side of my screen. I have a reasonible width set but it is not stopping the dropdown box from getting as wide as it needs to display each record. How can I set a fixed width on this?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1Usage" DataTextField="data_text" 
     DataValueField="ID" Width="280px">
</asp:DropDownList>here
```

Thanks,

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/UT4bf/ where it is the `<option>` values that are longer than you want?

Comment: Yes, exactly, the option values go way to wide on my ddl box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to set the style as follows:

```
<select id="yourselect" style="width: 100px; max-width: 100px">
    <option>...</option>
</select>
```

or

```
<div style="width: 100px; max-width: 100px">
    <select id="yourselect" style="width: 100%; position: relative">
        <option>...</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Maybe this helps...

Edit: Using the Attributes property:

markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboItems" runat="server" />
```

Code behind:

```
List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
{
    ListItem item = new ListItem();
    item.Text = string.Format("this is a very very long item text corresponding to the  number {0}", i);
    item.Value = i.ToString();
    items.Add(item);
}
cboItems.DataSource = items;
cboItems.DataBind();
// after data bind is complete
cboItems.Attributes["style"] = "width: 100px; max-width: 100px";
```

Maybe i didn't understand what you're trying to do, but this is what I meant with attributes.

Comment: Its a databound control so I have no way to assign properties to the control.

Comment: You can do that either on the code behind with the Attributes property or, you can do it on the markup even tho the "style" is not gonna come up on the intellisense.

Comment: That is what I was tyring to explain, there are no attributes. Let me try the div idea though. Nope, didn't work.

Comment: You could still apply the attributes property

Comment: I guess if I have to manually databind I could build the array and stick that into the control. Was hoping I would not have to hand code this.

Comment: Buddy.. my code is a sample, you don't have to do exactly like this...  if you want to use object data source or sql data source or any other, it's fine, but the control will still fire the data bound event, so, if you want to use the attributes property you can do after the bind is complete by creating an event handler to it, or use the HTML style attribute directly on the markup even tho this option won't appear on the intellisense at this point, it should still work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, and yes they work, but not when the control is activated, when the items appear in the scrollable dropdown list. this is when it goes full screen width because of long string text. Your code only seems to apply the width during rendering.

Answer (score 3):

have a look at css options

```
#myselect {
width:230px;
}
#myselect option {
width:220px;
}
```

more is here:

http://www.webmasterworld.com/html/3018783.htm

the answer i thing you want is  by penders

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS. Define style with fixed width and use it while creating dropdown box.

Comment: i have an embedded aspx page in a Master page and there is no <head> section to place style code on the page. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Then, link you css file in Master page's <head>.

Comment: Tried that and it still does not work. Tested in 3 browsers.